# speed up WebClient calls inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application, and i have the following call to do successive `WebClient()` calls to a 3rd party application:

```
public async Task<List<Technology>> GetResource(int? filtertype)
{

  try
  {
     using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
     {
         string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + token;
         var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
         resourcesinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourcesInfo>(json);
     }

     //for each resource get its tag + add the tag to the list
     foreach (var c in resourcesinfo.operation.Details)
     {    
        ResourceAccountListInfo resourceAccountListInfo = new ResourceAccountListInfo();
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
        {    
        string url = currentURL + "resources/" + c.RESOURCEID + "?AUTHTOKEN=" + token;
        string tempurl = url.Trim();    
        var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(tempurl);
        resourceAccountListInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAccountListInfo>(json);     
                       AllTags.Add(resourceAccountListInfo.SingleOrDefault().CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.ToLower());   
     }    
   }
}
```

currently the first `WebClient` will return around 1,500 records, so my second `WebClient` call inside the `foreach` will be executed 1,500 time, so the whole process is taking around 20 minutes to complete. So how can I improve this process?

Comment: Does the response to the user need to wait until all 1500 requests have completed?

Comment: @David yes the final result can not be send to the client unless the foreach loop is completed..

Comment: In that case I wonder if there's a way to batch them.  Mostly thinking out loud at the moment, so I don't have code to put into an answer.  But instead of calling `await` on each iteration of the loop, maybe loop over the records 5 at a time (configurable), building a `List<Task<T>>` of the results of `wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(tempurl)`, and then doing a `WaitAll` on that list.  So you'd have 5 parallel HTTP requests at a time instead of 1.  Tweak the 5 value as necessary.

Comment: @David parallel http requests might be an approach to follow, but not sure how i will be able to desrialize the return data for each of the parallel request and add it to the AllTag list i have inside the foreach ?

Comment: There may be a cleaner approach, but my first though would be to assign a `.ContinueWith()` to each `Task<T>` as it's being added to the list.  Inside that function you'd do whatever you need to do with the response (add it to `AllTags` it seems). So when the `WaitAll()` completes, that batch should be added to `AllTags` and it's time to start the next batch.  You'd want to make sure there's some careful error handling in the `.ContinueWith()` and the `WaitAll()` as well.  It can be easy for errors to go unnoticed in un-awaited tasks.

Comment: Issuing 1500+ requests to service 1, is insanely untenable. Nothing is really going to help you here; it's just not feasible. Most well-designed APIs will provide some way to batch requests (because they don't want you hitting it 1500+ times), or they'll provide some mechanism to include related items with the initial request. Many support paging, so that you can further reduce the load of each request. If you control the API, you need to implement these features, if you don't you need to either read the docs better or complain to the API owner.

Comment: If you truly have no other option, then you'll simply need to code around it. Perhaps by just listing the results of the initial request and making querying the details of each item opt-in via a link or button. At least that way, the user gets only what they need at the moment, quickly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt unfortunately the 3rd party API i am working with do not support getting what i need to single query , i have to define a foreach to get the results i want, so as a starting point i have to deal with the fact that i need to do 1,500 webclient calls to get the result i want... Now what do you think of using a parallel mechanize to issue let say 20 webclient requests at the same time (instead of one web-client at the same time) is this an approach which i can follow ?

Comment: @David can you provide some links which describe how i can implement your points ?

Comment: It's not just about parallelization. You're going to choke your network. Your server can't even handle doing 1500 connections, and especially if you're doing this for every, single request, you're going to grind everything to a screeching halt. When I said untenable, I meant *untenable*. You need to take a huge step back and re-evaluate.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i know things can not be 100% perfect in my case, as the API i am dealing with can not satisfy our requirments without having to do 1,500 webclient requests.. now the 3rd party API and the application i am initiating the WebClient from are inside our local network , so there should not be a huge network problem , beside this i do not want to initiate 1500 webclient requests at the same time , what i am asking is to initiate 20 webclient requests at the same time , this should have better performance , what do you think ? or from your point of view , how i can improve my code ?

Comment: You could do the iteration async very easly which might save you time by transforming the foreach call to a Parrael.ForEach() - this will let the tpl to optimise the number of cuncurrent calls, which usually does pretty good job.

Comment: @barakcaf but i can not use async methods inside a Paralle.Foreach ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some way to throttle the call to DownloadStringTaskAsync. You can either do it manually by using a semaphore and Task.Run or you could use the TPL Dataflow library to feed all the urls in and specify the degree of parallelism to your desired limit. Dataflow blocks will accept an async delegate (unlike Parallel.For)

```
private static async Task<Thing[]> ProcessAllUrls(string[] urls)
{
    var workBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Thing>(
        async url => await DownloadAndProcessUrl(url),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }
        );

    var outputBlock = new BufferBlock<Thing>();

    using (workBlock.LinkTo(outputBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
    {

        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            workBlock.Post(url);
        }

        // signal no more input going into workblock
        workBlock.Complete();

        // wait for workblock to pump all data into outputblock
        await workBlock.Completion;

        IList<Thing> finalResult = null;
        bool result = outputBlock.TryReceiveAll(out finalResult);
        return finalResult.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You do want to be careful doing parallel stuff inside a web server process though. While the WebClient calls are truly async from the CPU, the work you do deserializing the response will run on a thread pool thread which means it is competing with ASP.NET requests for CPU resources during this time

Comment: can you adivce on how i can transform my original webclient calls to use your approach ? seond point can you adivce more on what do you exactly mean by " the work you do deserializing the response will run on a thread pool thread which means it is competing with ASP.NET requests for CPU resources during this time" .. what will be the drawbacks of running parallel stuff inside a web server ?

Comment: in your original example you are looping over the Details collection and then (1) building the url, (2) invoking the url and (3) deserializing the result. If you just did step one and built all the urls first, then you could feed them into something like I posted. The DownloadAndProcessUrl call would do steps 2 & 3 and return a Technology. (in my example I called the output a Thing).

Inside a web server, each incoming request uses a thread from the thread pool. Each parallel thread you use also comes from the pool. The more of one impacts the other's performance.